# 12 V DC motor active indicator

Tags: led, dc-motor

I have two 12 V DC motors sharing the same input power supply connected in parallel sharing and spinning the same load thus splitting the work.

How can I attach an LED to each motor to inform me that each motor is indeed powered up and is running, but more importantly allow me to see if a particular motor is not active and needs service?

Each motor when powered up reaches a max current draw of about 2.5 A.

I thought about running an LED in series with a input connector on each motor thus giving me the status information I'm looking for but as we all know a led cannot handle a 2.5 A current following through it. So I quickly steered away from that idea.

As you can see I'm a little stuck. Thus any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you are using a motor driver such as the L298N bridge, you can attach a LED to the input side (enable, direction etc). If you are using PWM to interface a power MOSFET which in turn drive the motor, you can also the PWM signal to drive a LED at the same time. If you are indeed driving two motors at the output side, you can use shaft speed encoders to monitor status and speed as well. It would help if you give us a photo. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the motors are on the same power supply and not on separate power switches, LEDs in parallel will only tell you the power supply is active.

You need to detect some current flow (motor active) but not too much current flow (motor stalled or bogged down) - and you want to do it without losing very much voltage in the detector (2 V for a LED would only leave 10 V for the motor ... unacceptable!)

Here's a sketch of a solution, losing about 1 V in normal operation. If even that's too much, you'll need more sensitive amplifiers (probably opamps) to detect smaller voltages across lower resistance shunts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzAdSw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the voltage across R1 reaches about 0.6 V (1.5 A) Q1 turns on, and D1 lights.

When the voltage across R1 reaches 4*0.6 V (set by voltage divider R3, R4) Q2 turns on, and the red light illuminates. Note the lower forward voltage of D2 allows it to steal the current from R2, so D1 goes dark, so the light turns red indicating a stalled or overloaded motor.

(D1 and D2 are available in a single package with a common anode)

If you don't want overcurrent indication, omit D2, Q2, R3, R4.

Ad if 1 V drop is still too much, reduce R1, and insert a rail to rail opamp with a gain about 4, between R1 and Q1base/R3.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to connect the led in parallel with the motor use a current limiting resistor for the led else you will burn it out and whenever there is power to the motors the leds will turn on and when there is no supply the leds will turn off.

Ideally you can use a 220 ohm resistor it would be fine and a supply of 12V

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming the led needs to be the same voltage rating as the input and motor rating?

Comment: See you can control the voltage by inserting the resistor in the circuit and it will do your job. You can use the formula V= IR for LED resistance calculation you know the voltage you know the current so you can find the resistor value

Comment: Just thinking about the solution you originally offered. Yes your solution will indicate that there power flowing on that channel but you solution won't tell me if the motor itself is blow (not running) or is running. Thus your solution doesn't seem to be ideal to what I'm looking for correct?

Comment: Mmm I gues you are right it won't be ideal I guess if you want to check whether the motor is Blown off or not you will need a current meter or sensor which will sense the current when the motor is On or in use but when its blown off it won't show anything but still I will see if I can offer you anything else

Comment: Please reread the question. This won't give any information that the fact the shaft is spinning does not already more reliably provide.  Monitoring the power supply presence is not the goal.